# Uncaught TypeError: transactions.map is not a function in reacts JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch the API using Axios please help me resolve the below issues. I am a beginner for react js and getting Uncaught TypeError: transactions.map is not a function in reacts JS.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from './axios';
import './App.css';


function App() {
 const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState({transactions:[]});

 useEffect(() => {
   const fetchUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';

   async function fetchData(){
    const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);

    setTransactions(request.data);
    
    return request;
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);

console.log(transactions);


return (
  <div className="wrapper">
   <h2>Transactions</h2>
   <p>{transactions.total_pages}</p>
   <i>{transactions.map(datas => (
     <h2>{datas.data.avatar}</h2>
   ))}</i>
  
 </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The state you start with is an object, `{transactions: []}` and you then try to call `.map()` on that object, but`.map()` is only a method on arrays. Depending on your use case, you probably want `useState([])`. You have need to name state variables in object form with `useState()`

Comment: HI thank your valuable reply. I have done changes as you mentioned above. Still issue is the same.Any other ways to com out from this error

Answer (score 1):

As Andy said your transactions state is an object and `.map()` is a method on arrays. So, make it as an array `useState([])` and use it directly as `transactions.map()` or without changing your initial state use `transactions.transactions.map()`.

Comment: HI thank your valuable reply. I have done changes as you mentioned above. Still issue is the same.Any other ways to com out from this error.

Comment: Hello, I have tried with something similar, it works fine. You can check the code sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-ride-8sz7i.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your state from:**

```
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState({transactions:[]})
```

**To:**

```
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);
```

**Hope this helps you, Good Luck**

Comment: Hi I have done changes, here If I commented the map function. it is rendering the total_pages count. if I uncomment the map function again the same error

Comment: Wait some minutes I'm starting my React Dev server tos see what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching data from an api use the ternary operator `?`, just in case axios is still fetching data for example `transactions?.data?.map`. Try the following example it should work:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "./axios";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
       const fetchUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

       async function fetchData() {
       const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);

       setTransactions(request.data);

       return request;
      }
      fetchData();
    }, []);

   console.log(transactions);

   return (
        <div className="wrapper">
           <h2>Transactions</h2>
           <p>{transactions.total_pages}</p>
           <i>
               {transactions?.data?.map((datas) => (
                   <h2>{datas.avatar}</h2>
             ))}
          </i>
       </div>
   );
 }
export default App;
```

**Let me know if it works or not, Good Luck**

Comment: please vote for this answer it may help someone. Thanks